# How to rename a category name in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't rename the category name.

How can this be implemented?

```js
var obama = client.category.cache.get("7472173261......");
obama.setName(`СУД: ${text}`);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories are just channels ([CategoryChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel)) so if you want to rename them, you'll need to use [`client.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) to get them:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.cache.get(CATEGORY_ID);
const updatedChannel = await channel.setName('new category name');

console.log('channel updated to', updatedChannel.name);
```